# How write the Alias query usig Criteria in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, criteria

Hi i have a two Entity's and is mapped by using onetomany relationship unidirectional.I am going to write query by using criteria Alias to parent Entity,I want get the parent list based on only some child present in the childEntity, I have written like this.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria crit1 = session.createCriteria(RouteEntityClass.class);
        crit1.add(Restrictions.eq("routeType", "Pick"));
        crit1.createAlias("points", "point");
        Criterion point1 = Restrictions.eq("point.pointAutoId", 26l);
        Criterion pont2 = Restrictions.eq("point.pointAutoId", 27l);
        LogicalExpression orExp = Restrictions.and(point1, pont2);
        crit1.add(orExp);
        List<RouteEntityClass> list = crit1.list();
        for (RouteEntityClass rec : list) {
            System.out.println("recccccccccccc" + rec.getRouteId());
        }
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you really name all your classes with a `Class` suffix, and all your entities with a `EntityClass` suffix? How about naming it `Route` instead?

Comment: I have two entity called RouteEntity and PointEntity,Here RouteEntity I have mapped has many to one to pointEntity that has one more table called route_point table.Now I need to write query to get routes Only some particuler point Peresent.

Comment: And? What is your question? A question is a sentence that ends with a question mark. You posted some code. What's wrong with it?